# Bad translation "No need of cash?"

Tags: translation

I have seen an advertisement for a restaurant which starts to accept prepaid company access cards. The text is written in native language and in English.

English variant: "No need of cash?"

My translation of czech variant: "Don't you have a cash?"

I think that their translation is wrong. I would rather express it as: "No cash?"

Can somebody elaborate on this topic? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question mark is certainly off.

Also, I would not use *of*, but *for*. No need of cash sounds as if I am asking you to hand over your excess cash. You have cash you have no use for? I'll take it off your hands!

As a slogan they could use:

> No need for cash.

Meaning that you do not need to have cash on you in order to pay.

*If* however the rest of the advertisement follows up on the *question*, which I *suspect* it does, you need to keep the translation also as a question, of course. Your "No cash?" is a fine solution for that:

> No cash? No problem!

Comment: so their "No need of cash?" is incorrect, is not it?

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect. Because of the question mark, and the use of _of_. :)

Comment: I just saw it again: "No need of cash? Pay with your Siemens card!"

Comment: @LeosLiterak That is indeed a very badly formed slogan. I wish some companies would let someone proofread their translations before plastering them all over in public - but then again, it can be quite amusing :) They basically say "If you do not need any money, use this card", in other words, "our card will surely cost you money!"

Comment: You should have seen their other papers. E.g. "How to build islands of safety" slogan illustrated with skyscrapers flooded by stormy sea :-) (side note: is my sentence correct? with or by skyscpapers; stormy)

Comment: @LeosLiterak - with or by are both correct, stormy is correct :) I would say "**a** stormy sea" though :)

Comment: Thanks. I always have troubles with that articles (a, an, the). Maybe idea for next question.